# Remove the last child from a gameobject

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, destroy

I'm creating a custom keyboard for a touchscreen application that outputs an image when a button is pressed. These images then populate a grid layout to keep things organized linearly. I need a backspace button. I'm really struggling with the backspace. I'm having trouble finding the problem with the code attached. When I hit the deleteKey button nothing happens, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but I want it to remove the last child in the messagePanel gameobject.

```
List<GameObject> msgSymbols = new List<GameObject>();
public string prefabPath;
int msgLength;

Vector3 symbolPos;
GameObject symbolChar;
GameObject msgPanel;
Vector3 symbolScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

GameObject[] symbolKeys;
GameObject deleteKey;

void Awake()
{
    msgPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MessagePanel");
    symbolKeys = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SymbolKey");
    deleteKey = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DeleteKey");
}

#region IPointerClickHandler implementation

public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (transform.CompareTag("SymbolKey"))
    {

        symbolChar = Instantiate(Resources.Load (prefabPath)) as GameObject;    // Instantiate an symbol
        symbolChar.transform.SetParent(msgPanel.transform);                     // Parent it to grid
        symbolChar.transform.localScale = symbolScale;                          // Set scale of all objects added
        symbolPos = symbolChar.transform.position;                              // Find position of objects in grid
        msgLength = msgPanel.transform.childCount;

        foreach(Transform t in msgPanel.transform)                              // Create running list of symbol objects added to messagePanel
        {
            msgSymbols.Add(t.gameObject); 
        }

        Debug.Log (msgLength);
    }

    else if (transform.CompareTag("DeleteKey"))
    {
        if(msgSymbols.Count == 0) return;
        Destroy(msgSymbols.LastOrDefault());

        // Old attempts

        // msgSymbols.RemoveAt(msgLength - 1);
        // Destroy(msgSymbols[msgSymbols.Count-1]);
    }

}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

if count is 0 you'll get a index of -1 which is out of the index range.

```
if(messageSymbols.Count > 0) Destroy(messageSymbols.LastOrDefault());
```

Comment: LastOrDefault seems to be redundant since we already know that element exists so we can go with Last().

Comment: there is no performance implications and you should get into the habit of using `...OrDefault` no matter what the context.

Comment: I'm not getting the Last or LastOrDefault methods in my code complete, is there a particular namespace I need to access these?

Comment: This is crazy I cannot get this to work! What am I doing wrong here? Are the objects that I'm instantiating in the msgPanel that same as the ones going into the List? Something isn't intersecting here. I've updated code above to latest iteration. How can I debug this to see what the Destroy is trying to 'destroy'?

Comment: `Debug.Log(msgSymbols.LastOrDefault().name);`

Comment: That's insteresting. Debug is throwing this: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How can that be? Where would I set the object instance instance?

Comment: that means that you are not populating `msgSymbols`. `Debug` the length of `msgSymbols`

Answer (score 1):

Check that array has at least 1 value before delete :

```
else if (transform.CompareTag("DeleteKey"))
{
    if(messageSymbols.Count == 0) return;
    Destroy(messageSymbols[messageSymbols.Count-1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabjan - that got rid of the out of range error, but it revealed another problem. Clicking the DeleteKey still doesn't remove the last symbolCharacter from the messagePanel. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you check if there is object at msgSymbols[msgSymbols.Count-1] at all ? It seems that msgSymbols is always empty or null

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of the problem, but you should probably also [`RemoveAt(length-1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx) the last object from `messageSymbols`. `Destroy` will, well, destroy the object, but the element is still in the `List`.